# Programmatically input text to website text field

Tags: c#, html

Would be thankful if you showed me why it doesn't work. When I press the button nothing happens.

```
//    <input type="text" name="nick" value="" size="25" tabindex="1" maxlength="50" class="material-input" required="">

  private void loginName()
    {     
        HtmlElementCollection classButton = webBrowser1.Document.All;
        foreach (HtmlElement element in classButton)
        {
            if (element.GetAttribute("material-input") == "input")
            {
                element.SetAttribute("name", "abcdfefefefe");
            }
        }    
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginName();
    }
```

EDIT: 
Is this a good solution ?

```
  var loginElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")["nick"];
        passwordElement.SetAttribute("value", "abcdfefefefe");
```

Comment: One problem is `GetAttribute` takes the attribute name, not its value.

Comment: In addition to what Crowcoder said, in your if statement you're changing the value of the name attribute. If you want that text in the textfield then you should be changing its value.